# Error 13 en tiempo de ejecución en una macro que da formato de tabla a datos en un texto

Tags: excel, vb

Caundo intento ejecutar la siguiente macro, aparece un error 13 en tiempo de ejecucion.

Cuando voy al depurador, me indica que el error ocurre en la última linea del codigo que muestro:

```
Function QAD_MRP_Read23_14() As Boolean

    Dim reportFileName As String
    Dim bCancelled As Boolean
    Dim inData() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim auxText As String
    Dim batch As Integer

    Call Util_VbaDecimalSeparator

'    Call Util_GetFilePath(reportFileName, bCancelled, "Select 23.14 report TXT file", "*.txt", "*.TXT")

'    If reportFileName = vbNullString Then
'        GoTo QAD_MRP_Read23_14_End
'    End If

'    inData = Util_Read_UTF_8_Text_File(reportFileName)
    inData = Util_Read_Clipboard_Text
    qty = NumElems(inData)

    If InStr(1, inData(0), "23.14", vbTextCompare) <> 56 Then
        MsgBox "Error! Data in clipboard invalid", vbOKOnly, "QAD 23.14"
        QAD_MRP_Read23_14 = False
        GoTo QAD_MRP_Read23_14_End
    End If


    Set report = New QAD_MRP_Report

    For i = 2 To qty - 1
        auxText = inData(i)

        If Left(auxText, 14) = "     Articulo:" Then
            batch = 0
            currItem = report.AddItem(auxText) - 1
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 14) = " Cnt en Exist:" Then
            Call report.Add2Line(currItem, auxText)
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 14) = " Política Ord:" Then
            Call report.Add3Line(currItem, auxText)
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 14) = "   Períod Ord:" Then
            Call report.Add4Line(currItem, auxText)
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 14) = "     Cant Ord:" Then
            Call report.Add5Line(currItem, auxText)
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 22) = "                Pasado" Then
            Call report.AddDates(currItem, batch, auxText, inData(i + 1))
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 14) = "Req brutos    " Then
            Call report.AddRequirements(currItem, batch, auxText)
        ElseIf Left(auxText, 14) = "Recibo Progmd " Then
```

el codigo no lo generé yo y estoy teniendo problemas para resolver el inconveniente agradezco caulquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: El código está incompleto?

Comment: El código que has puesto está incompleto.